# Delegate Subdomain to Azure via CNAME

Tags: azure, dns, subdomain, azure-web-app-service, azure-dns

the company I’m working for provided me a subdomain. test.mycomp.com . I want to add it to my azure web app via custom domain.

The azure system recommends a CNAME delegation and provided me the information to enter web-zeudz-staging.azurewebsites.net in the dns management as CNAME.

After doing so and verifiying via DNS Lookup, Azure always gives me „Domain Ownership Error“. What can I do to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

Is your DNS provider also a CDN provider, for example cloudflare? If so, turn off the CDN/proxy function so it's a DNS only record and try again.

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer. I thought about that, but it will be impossible to check or do so. My DNS provider is the company I'm working for and a global player. They will never turn off any CDN/proxy function.

Comment: There's actually one simple way to tell. Ping web-zeudz-staging.azurewebsites.net ; then Ping subdomain.test.mycomp.com. if the resolved IPs are different it means you're behind a CDN/Reverse proxy.

Comment: Hi thanks for the info. I did the ping test and it resolved the same IP. So there isn't any CDN. But what could then be the problem?

Comment: I just tested the following: I own a private Domain. I added CNAME Entry to point to Azure and of course it works perfectly. If I do the lookup it looks exactly the same like the company one which is not working.

Comment: Does your company use split DNS? If so, is your DNS record definitely with your public DNS provider?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have any control over the CDN function you can use txt record validation. 
Create your TXT record `awverify.subdomain.test.mycomp.com` with value `web-zeudz-staging.azurewebsites.net` and validate again. It should succeed.

There's also a CNAME `awverify` method but you need CDN disabled for that too.

I find it strange that your company doesn't have the option to enable/disabled CDN for any given DNS entry though.